# AWS SNS Mobile Push based on user notification preferences

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm working SNS Push notifications into an app that I'm building, and I'm wondering how to handle user notification settings? What I don't understand is if SNS provides a way to manage a user who wants to receive notification type "A", but not type "B".  A more real-world correlation is managing a Facebook user who wants notifications for comments, but not likes. Does SNS provide an easy way to manage this?

I can manage it myself through my own servers/databases, but this seems like something that SNS should be able to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest each notification type is a different SNS topic. That way the user can control each topic he is subscribed too. That puts more work for you in your app but this way you get to your designed goal of allowing each user to subscribe to each a different type of notification.

Topics are free but SNS messages sent are charged.

FREE TIER: Each month, Amazon SNS customers receive 1,000,000 Amazon SNS Requests, 100,000 HTTP notifications, 1,000 email notifications and 100 SMS notifications for free.

Cost calculator: http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

SNS Pricing Details: https://aws.amazon.com/sns/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

No. SNS does not provide a way to manage users to subscribe based on notification types

In fact there is no implicit notification type definitions. Although you can have that as part of your payload.

So you can either

1. Have different topics for different notification types and then attach subscribers based on which type of messages they are interested in
2. Have a type definition defined within the payload and then let the filtering happen at the subscribers. But keep in mind that this will be costly affair because all subscribers receive all notifications and you can soon exhaust your free limit. Also the subscribers will receive unnecessary load